Defining different /prefix style in Customize CurVe CV
So I'm using LianTze Lim's A Customised CurVe CV to create my CV. Instead of the FontAwesome5 "bookmark" I'd like to be able to define different symbols for different entries (no matter what section they are in).
Here is how the prefix is defined in the settings.sty
 \newcommand{\prefixmarker}[1]{\def\@prefixmarker{#1}}
\def\@prefixmarker{\relscale{.9}\faBookmark}

\prefix{%
  \hspace*{-1ex}
  \color{MarkerColour!80!black}\@prefixmarker%
  \hspace*{1ex}%
}

So for example, to create the education section, the following code is needed:
 \begin{rubric}{Education}
\entry*[2009 -- 2013]%
    \textbf{Ph.D., Unseen University} High Energy Magic.
    \par Thesis title: \emph{Low-Cost Mana Generation in Under-Resouced Evironments.}
%
\entry*[2003 -- 2006]%
    \textbf{M.Sc.~Computer Science, Unseen} in High Energy Magic.\par
    Thesis title: \emph{Applying ant algorithms in automatic design of novel magic charms}.
% 
\entry*[2003 -- 2006]%
    \textbf{M.Sc.~Computer Science, Unseen} in High Energy Magic.\par
    Thesis title: \emph{Applying ant algorithms in automatic design of novel magic charms}.
\end{rubric}

For each entry, a small bookmark icon appears before the listed item, which then looks like this:

How do I change the little red bookmark icon? I have a list of all the FontAwesome5 symbols, but need to know how to specify which icon to use for which entry.

Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Add the following to your preamble:
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\@sentry}{O{} O{\faBookmark}}{%
  \gdef\@nextentry{\\\par}\@key{#1}\egroup
  \@@key & \prefixmarker{#2}\@prefix &}
\makeatother

This updates the way a starred \entry works within the rubric environment. Specifically it adds a second optional argument where you can specify the symbol being displayed. Now you can specify symbols individually, with the default remaining \faBookmark:
\begin{rubric}{Education}
\entry*[2009 -- 2013][\faTwitter]%
    \textbf{Ph.D., Unseen University} High Energy Magic.
    \par Thesis title: \emph{Low-Cost Mana Generation in Under-Resouced Evironments.}
%
\entry*[2003 -- 2006][\faGlobe]%
    \textbf{M.Sc.~Computer Science, Unseen} in High Energy Magic.\par
    Thesis title: \emph{Applying ant algorithms in automatic design of novel magic charms}.
% 
\entry*[2003 -- 2006]%
    \textbf{M.Sc.~Computer Science, Unseen} in High Energy Magic.\par
    Thesis title: \emph{Applying ant algorithms in automatic design of novel magic charms}.
\end{rubric}



Thank you so much, Werner! Super helpful!
